Allure reports: AllureRestAssured duolicates requests and responses in reports
I am struggling to find a solution for requests/responses duplication in allure reports.
I have several test classes with tests and they all inherit from a base class.
In a base class under @BeforeAll method I have:
RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;
RestAssured.filters(new AllureRestAssured());

All requests run only once, but Allure shows them several times(the same request is copied multiple times and then a response). I ran them many times in Intellij to check that I don't have request duplication and added some logs. the problem is only in Allure reports. All tests under the same class have the same amount of duplicates in the report(2/3/4/5 requests/responses).
an example of a duplicated request
Any ideas about what causes these duplicates? It is super confusing
different test classes - different amount of duplicates
6 duplicates
Don't see this problem with logs in IntelliJ IDEA (add them as an attachment to each test)
Happens all the time.
